# Move add to cart to below price (and above description) Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

How can I move the add to cart button immediately below the price in Magento 2? I presume it's an XML update but I am unsure of the code required.

I want to move it from under the description to above the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy "catalog_product_view.xml" file to your theme.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/{{vendortheme}}/{{theme}}/Magento_Catalog/layout
```

add below tag in body

```
<move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.price"  after="-" />
```

catalog_product_view file like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>           
        <move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.price" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I have applied the change in the file... redeployed static and cleared cache... but the page doesn't update. Any further advise please?

Comment: did you override catalog_product_view.xml file in your theme or custom module

Comment: Got it working Monarch. It seemed to be that I had to rm some of the var/ files. They must have been caching a layout element?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add below code in `catalog_product_view.xml` file under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>
```